# How do you identify if sql server instance is an 'always on' replica?

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

is there a way to interrogate a sql server instance or db to identify that it is an alwayson replica?

Answer (score 0):

You could query `sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states` and then see if your database is in there.

```
SELECT DB_NAME ( database_id )  , * FROM sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states
```